# running multiple JBOSS instances as services

Tags: jboss

I was able to configure multiple instances of JBOSS 4.2.3 by changing certain ports and run two different servers at the same time. However is there anyway to run multiple instances of JBOSS as services ? Have already set the JBOSS_HOME in environment variables . Is it possible to set multiple paths for JBOSS_HOME in environment variables. For example ,  One path would be the default JBOSS_HOME folder and the other the JBOSS_HOME for the instance which i have created .